# Wrapping shell built-ins

Tags: bash, shell, metaprogramming

I'd like to wrap the built-in Bash command `export` so that it logs the variable being exported.

In a language like JavaScript, if I want to wrap a built-in, I can save a reference to the original object.  So, for instance, we could make the built-in `alert` capitalize its argument:

```
var originalAlert = alert;
alert = function(s) {
  originalAlert(s.toUpperCase());
}
```

But since Bash doesn't have references like this, I don't think it's possible to wrap `export` with the same technique.

Am I wrong? Is there some way to wrap a bash built-in like `export`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call a builtin, even if it has been overridden by a function, with the `builtin` command:

```
export() {
    echo "$@"
    builtin export "$@"
}
```